# Why can't I authenticate my Google API with Postman?

Tags: authentication, spring-security, oauth-2.0, oauth, google-oauth

I am building a Java Spring app, which requires user authentication.
I registered it as a Google API, with a goal to make it so users can use their Google accounts to authenticate. It uses OAuth 2.

When I log in with the browser, everything works - I can log in with my google account, however when I set up an access token in Postman,
and then use it to authorize requests, it seems to ignore it, returning the html of Google's login
window whether I send the request with the token or without it.

OAuth 2 access tokens have a few URLs to set. I tried to set them as follows:

Callback URL: `https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback`
Auth URL: `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth`
Access Token URL: `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token`

My Spring Security configuration so far:

```
SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    return httpSecurity
        .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
            auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
        })
        .oauth2Login(withDefaults())
        .build();
}
```

Do you know what might be the issue?